# What is the exact meaning of the statement "The expression e is used as a glvalue if and only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue" in [conv]/6

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

[[conv]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#6) (emphasis is mine):

> The effect of any implicit conversion is the same as performing the
>   corresponding declaration and initialization and then using the
>   temporary variable as the result of the conversion. The result is an
>   lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to
>   function type ([dcl.ref]), an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference to
>   object type, and a prvalue otherwise. **The expression e is used as a
>   glvalue if and only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue**.

What is the meaning of the highlighted statement above, in the context of this specific paragraph?

Comment: **If and only if** is a mathematical term: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if)

Comment: a **glvalue** is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object, bit-field, or function: [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Answer (score 2):

The intent of that sentence is to clarify that an expression like `i` (where `i` is a variable) is not spuriously treated as a glvalue in contexts in which `i` is immediately converted to a prvalue.

For instance, in

```
int main() {
  const int j = 0;
  constexpr int i = j;
}
```

The second definition would be ill-formed if `j` was considered a glvalue, as [`j` is not a permitted result of a constant expression](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5). However, `j` is used as a prvalue since the initialization uses it as one, hence the other rule in the linked paragraph applies (and the definition is well-formed).